# Visual Studio Error Con Tablas

Tags: visual-studio

En la siguiente imagen muestro mi error de Visual Studio 2015 en el cual cuando selecciono el lugar que dice Tablas siguiente mente segundo Click y luego en actualizar me muestra el siguiente error necesito ver esa tabla pero me dice

> No se puede cargar archivo o ensamblado
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Managment.Sdk ni una de sus dependencias. El
>   sistema no pueda encontrar el archivo especificado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que tipo de base de datos estas usando SQLServer, Access...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se da ya que Visual Studio no pudo encontrar el assembly requerido para SQL Server 2014.

Descarga estos 2 archivos en versión `X86` o `X64` segun corresponda a tu sistema:

- DB2OLEDBV5
- SharedManagementObjects.msi

https://www.microsoft.com/es-ES/download/details.aspx?id=42295

Luego de instalar reinicia el visual studio.

Comment: Hola Renzo, talvés explicando del por qué son necesarios esos archivos dejará más claro y una posible respuesta al OP, en mi caso, no entendí del por qué esos dos archivos se necesitan instalar si el error corresponde a una referencia.

Comment: Gracias me funciono!!!!